# Postgresql order by desc nulls last on every query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Is there a configuration option somewhere or anything that will allow me to force postgres to use NULLS LAST on every query that uses DESC ordering?

I dont want to rewrite all queries from Criteria API to JPQL in my app, and it seems JPA Criteria API does not allow setting nulls last option.

Comment: You can work around not being able to sort nulls by using something like `ORDER BY (column IS NULL), column DESC`. `false` comes first in `ASC` order so by default nulls will be last. I don't know about configuration tho.

Answer (score 2):

No. At least I never heard of such. Simple check does not give hope for it either:

```
t=# select setting, name from pg_settings where name like '%null%';
 setting |         name
---------+-----------------------
 on      | array_nulls
 off     | transform_null_equals
(2 rows)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-order.html does not mention such global switches either, just:

> The NULLS FIRST and NULLS LAST options can be used to determine
>   whether nulls appear before or after non-null values in the sort
>   ordering. By default, null values sort as if larger than any non-null
>   value; that is, NULLS FIRST is the default for DESC order, and NULLS
>   LAST otherwise.